# Problems accessing WindowsForms after creating FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, multithreading

For my project, I need to trigger a method, that changes the text in some textboxes after a file was created inside a given directory.

Therefore, I used a FileSystemWatcher and added an EventHandler to it as you can see here:

```
private void watch()
    {

        watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = path;
        watcher.Filter = "*.osr";
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
```

After a file is created, the FileSystemWatcher successfully triggers the method, but an error is raised when I want to access the textboxes.

```
textBox.Text = path; //Error here
```

The error is: "System.InvalidOperationException" and it says, that I'm trying to access WindowsForms from another thread, but I never created another thread...

The fun thing is, that I also have a button to do the whole thing manually (so opening a file manually) and it works perfectly fine there.

Can you tell me why it is in another thread or how I could fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your FileSystemWatcher is on one thread and your UI on another one.

You need to call it using BeginInvoke, so it will be "managed" at the same thread of your UI.

Something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    delegate void FileCreationUpdater(FileSystemEventArgs evt);
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = null;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // instantiate a new FileSystemWatcher
        watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments))
        {
            // and starts it right away
            EnableRaisingEvents = true
        };

        // create a new updater delegate 
        FileCreationUpdater updater = new FileCreationUpdater(TextBoxUpdater);

        // when receiving Created events, Invoke updater.
        watcher.Created += (s, e) =>
        {
            /// passing parameter to the invoked method
            textBox1.BeginInvoke(updater, e);
        };
    }

    public void TextBoxUpdater(FileSystemEventArgs evt)
    {
        /// update path
        textBox1.Text = evt.FullPath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The FileSystemWatcher will run on a separate thread so rather than trying to read the path from the other thread just do a lookup in the directory and see what has changed.  Sorry in a rush so can't give a full answer.

Comment: Ok so that answers the error, but I need to be checking the whole time and everytime a new file gets created I need to trigger the method. Can I somehow change the text of the windowsforms even from the other thread?